# Как сделать предварительный просмотр картинок в форме и передача картинки на сервер без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Как сделать предварительный просмотр картинок в форме и передача картинки на сервер без перезагрузки страницы. У меня есть код загрузки картинки на сервер и в базу данных, но это все проходит с перезагрузкой страницы. Хотелось бы сделать предпросмотр картинки и после уже загружать картинки на сервер без перезагрузки.
1) файл обработчик
    $uploaddir = 'i/';

```
$apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.jpg'; 

$uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend"; 

$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

if(($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] != 0 and $_FILES['userfile']['size']<=1024000)) 
{ 

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
   { 

        $c="INSERT INTO images (name) VALUES('".$uploadfile."')";

        $q=$dbh->prepare($c);

        $q->execute();

   $size = getimagesize($uploadfile); 

     if ($size[0] < 5001 && $size[1]<5001) 
     { 

     echo "Файл загружен. Путь к файлу: <b>http://led.remturbo.ru/".$uploadfile."</b>"; 
     } else {
     echo "Загружаемое изображение превышает допустимые нормы (ширина не более - 500; высота не более 1500)"; 
     unlink($uploadfile); 

     } 
   } else {
   echo "Файл не загружен, вернитеcь и попробуйте еще раз";
   } 
} else { 
echo "Размер файла не должен превышать 5000Кб";
}
```

2) форма

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
<form name="upload" action="load.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"> 
Выберите файл для загрузки: 
<input type="file" name="userfile">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Загрузить"> 

</form>

<?
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT name FROM images');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
?><img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="/<?= $row['name'] ?>">  
<?}
?>
<?
if(isset($_POST['del']))
{
    unlink($uploadfile);

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JS**:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/) (с) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

**UPD**
Ajax отправка формы:

```
$("form#form1").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'load.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

(с) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

Comment: еще вопрос как сделать чтобы страница не перезагружалась после отправки формы ?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: последний вопрос. В ajax мне выводит alert(data) всю страницу во сплывающем окне, как грамотно мне вывести результат (картинку), пробовал вот так $('#ajaxDiv').html(data); #ajaxDiv- див, не получилось в интернете видел пример чтобы в

Comment: `alert(data)` - ответ от `load.php`. Вам нужно минимум отправлять GOOD  если все удачно или BAD если сохранение не прошло. На основание ответов уже предпринимать дальнейшие действия - как минимум уведомить пользователя об результатт операции и далее либо запросить повторную отправку или продолжить дальше по цепочки задуманного....